# Suppose we know for certain that P = NP. Can we say that NP = co-NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

i tried to see from my course book at university but i didn't understand much, can someone help me? even looking around on the internet I did not find anything useful

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

$NP=P=co-P=co-NP$

Where $P=co-P$ since $P$ is closed under complement (the TMs are deterministic and always halt, simply swap "reject" with "accept")

Answer (score 0):

P is the class of decision problems where you can find the correct answer in polynomial time in all cases.

Now instead of X: “What is the answer” you can solve X’ “is the answer YES” or X’’ “is the answer NO” in polynomial time.

Since X, X’ and X’’ are in P, they are in NP. X’’ can be solved in nondeterministic polynomial time if the answer to X’’ is “YES”, which is exactly if the answer to X is “NO”. So be definition, X is in co-NP.